# javascript insertAfter alternatives to nextSibling hack?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="cat1"></div>
<div id="cat2"></div>
<div id="cat3"></div>
</div>
```

I can do a insertBefore but there is no insertAfter... what if I want to append another cat to the container? Do I really have to use a nextSibling? It fells very strange that there is an insertBefore and for an insertAfter one has to use a hack. Are there alternatives to

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
insertAfter(document.getElementById("tres"), myscript);
```

Comment: No, what you have is really fine.

Comment: You could do `parent.insertBefore(new, old); parent.insertBefore(old, new);` This would simulate an `insertAfter` by doing a swap.

Comment: @Bergi I found that as well, but technically OP is asking if there's something *better* than the answer to that question.

Comment: @ajp15243: Obviously not, otherwise it would have become the top answer there :-) Basically it's the same question, asking for the "best way".

Comment: I have an alternative way, it's not great, and adds garbadge, add a div with id containerEnd and do insertBefore(elem, containerEnd). It's an alternative, but not a better one.

Answer (score 5):

Since you can combine `insertBefore` and `nextSibling`, there is no need for another function. `insertBefore` has the added bonus of behaving like `appendChild` if the second argument is null.

You can extend the prototype chain to implement `insertAfter` like so:

```
Node.prototype.insertAfter = function(n,r) {this.insertBefore(n,r.nextSibling);};
```

This will allow you to call:

```
someContainer.insertAfter(newNode, someReference);
```

Note that older versions of IE don't like you [messing with the prototype of built-in objects](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: You might want to use `r ? r.nextSibling : this.firstChild` :-)

Comment: Indeed I will have to for something like this since I am adding hundreds of slides one after another. I even thought about adding a DOM element and doing <div id="containerEnd"></div> and then use the insertBefore(newdiv,containerEnd); it feels a bit more natural to use, but adds garbage, it's very strange. That is one want's to insertAfter, one has to use insertBefore.

Comment: Wait... you're trying to add it as the last element? What's wrong with `appendChild`?

Comment: I am actually adding with no exact order, but at load I am lading them all one after the other.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this following function instead of your method you will get solution.

```
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {   
newNode.insertBefore(referenceNode.next());
```

}

Comment: And what is this `next()` method?